# Using Riemann-Stieltjes integration for Chebychev function

Tags: number-theory

Using  Riemann-Stieltjes integration the following expression is true according to pp 4-5 of http://math.tufts.edu/faculty/rlemkeoliver/teaching/250/02-RiemannStieltjes.pdf
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log p_n &=& \int_2^n \log k\;  d\pi(k)  \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}$$
by doing the integration this way it neatly leads to:
$$\theta(n) = \log (t) \pi(t) \Big|_2^n - \int_2^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt. \tag{2}$$

By swapping functions is there any reason apart from the extra difficulty involved with some approximations of $\pi(k)$ why the following statement (3) could or even would not be true? If so why?

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log p_n &=& \int_2^n \pi(k)\;  d(\log k)   \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: (3) can't be true because the RHS is continuous in $n$. What is your question ? $\int_2^n f(x)d\pi(x)$ is ambiguous because $\pi(x)$ is discontinuous at the boundary. $\int_{2-\epsilon}^{n+\epsilon}f(x) d \pi(x)   = \sum_{p \le n} f(p)$ by definition, and yes integration by parts works as expected. Also $\pi'(x) = \sum_p \delta(x-p)$ in the sense of distributions ($\delta$ is the Dirac delta) and $d\pi(x) =  \sum_p d1_{x > p}$ where $ d1_{x > 0} =d \nu$ with $\nu $ the Dirac measure.

Comment: @reruns yes that was the question is (3) possible? not according to what you've said. So if I've understood it does not work because log is continuous and $\pi(x)$ is not

Comment: Well integrate by parts (1) and (3) you'll see the terms you missed. You can use the notation $dg(x) = g'(x)dx$ even with $g(x) =\pi(x)$.

Comment: @reruns thanks for pointing out  that one can use $dg(x) = g'(x)dx$ I was not aware of that even though I wondered why.